# Scheduled task is not running or showing up in Task Scheduler - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

I'm running Windows 10 v. 1607 (OS Build 14393.351) on a desktop computer

I created a task in Task Scheduler, and it allowed me to create the task, which was to run a program. . I set it to run 'At startup' delayed 1 minute. I set it to 'Run with highest privileges' Configured for Windows 10. I set it to allow running on demand. When I rebooted my computer the program didn't start.

When I went back to Task Scheduler and looked in the Task Scheduler Library the entry wasn't there. I refreshed the list and it still didn't show. I moved back up to the main Task Scheduler directory and the summary of current tasks (79 items). The task didn't show up there either. I refreshed both lists and it still didn't show.

I thought maybe it hadn't been created so I tried to create it again. When I got to the end of creating it I got the error message:

"An error has occurred for task Launch 'Program Name'. Error message: A task or folder with this name already exists"

So it says it exists, but as mentioned it doesn't run at startup, and doesn't show on the list. I can still run the program on demand no problem.

I tried creating it again, both as a full Task and a Basic Task. Each time I get the error message:

"An error has occurred for task Launch 'Program Name'. Error message: A task or folder with this name already exists"

How can I find where the program task is in Task Scheduler and why isn't it showing up?

Answer (score 3):

Have you already tried navigating to `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks` to see if it appears there?  If it isn't visible, try performing a search within that folder hierarchy.  Just to double-check, is it possible that the task name you chose matches a default/built-in Windows task that already exists?

Also, please ensure that you proceed with caution.  Anything you do within that folder hierarchy will have a tangible impact upon your Windows operating system.

Any task within that folder hierarchy *should* appear in your `Task Scheduler Library`.  If it doesn't and you find your problematic task in `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks`, you should be able to delete it from that folder and recreate it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

it is old post, but i had similar problem. I created task, it is shown in
c:\windows\system32\task, but in task scheduler i could not see my task. Task job was always successfully executed, but i could not managed because i could not see it. What i did to solve problem was: First in view tab i deselected show hidden task (if it is selected), then with up arrow that appears on the top of task sections, like task history etc, i closed all panes. Then i saw my task listed, i just right clicked with mouse, and whoala normal view appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the Task Scheduler with administrator privileges? That did the trick for me. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42717238/7909205.